# How to modify Http Method in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, compact-framework, httpwebresponse

In HttpWebRequest a user can pass Method as Post OR Get OR Put OR DELETE etc.

But for our specific project I need to pass HttpMethod as "POST /api/login HTTP/1.0".

But this is not allowed in .NET CF.

Then can any one tell me workaround for this please for customizing Http Method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"But this is not allowed in .NET CF."_ What do you mean? What code do you use to do that? What errors do you get?

Comment: Hi CodeCaster, I am trying following code :                 HttpWebRequest hbWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(WebService+"/api/login");
                hbWebRequest.Method = "POST /api/login HTTP/1.0";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) states:

> The Method property can be set to any of the HTTP 1.1 protocol verbs: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, or OPTIONS.

So simply use `hbWebRequest.Method = "POST";`.

Answer (score 5):

The reason that this isn't allowed in .NET CF is because it's nonsensical: there isn't a HttpMethod matching what you listed.

I think you are mistaken.  Your method is `POST`, your target url is `/api/login` and the protocol is `HTTP/1.0`.  So, you should be making a `HttpWebRequest` to that Url.

Comment: Hi Dan, Thanks for your reply. But this is possible in Objective C. So, is there any way around for this.

Comment: It may be *possible* in objective C, but that doesn't mean it's valid.  A HttpMethod with that value isn't allowed by the Http spec.